# How to make Instagram image layout in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, user-interface, instagram

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhxVZ.jpg)
Instagram image layout on the search screen withe pictures of different height and width

Answer (score 0):

You should use FlatList. Every FlatList item will consist of 5 pre-prepared Views. You should start from this https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist

@BeginnerProgrammer
Every FlatList item will consist of 5 containers with image in it. If FlatList item have only 4 images - structure of item will be the same.

So the feed data should be not an array, it should be multidimensional array.

For example:
All items (arrays) with odd indexes will have prearranged structure with full height image at the **right** side of contaner.
All items (arrays) with even indexes will have prearranged structure with full height image at the **left** side of contaner.

Something like on picture.
[image: feed]

Comment: What did you mean by 5 prepared views?